# When upgrading from Win10 Home to Pro will any files/apps/user-folders/environment-vars/Win10-Settings be deleted or modified in anyway?

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-pro

Aside from the new features being added and minor changes here and there, will any files/apps/user-folders/environment-vars/Win10-Settings be deleted or modified in anyway?

I don't think it will based on what I've researched, but I haven't exactly gotten 100% confirmation, and I would like that :) which leads me here :)

I have Windows 10 Home with an Windows 10 Home activation key already installed and running for the past year on my PC,
and will be upgrading to Windows 10 Pro through the ->
Windows search box -> Settings -> Update & Security -> Activation -> "Go to the Store" link -> Upgrade to Windows 10/11 Pro -> Install -> "Yes, let's go"

---

## Update After Upgrading

I upgraded and absolutely nothing appears to have been deleted or modified.

- All my Windows 10 Home settings appear to be the same.
- All my Environment & System variables were the same.
- All my apps were still
  there and the same.
- My C:/Users/ folders were the same.
- My drivers, network settings, bluetooth pairings, monitor settings, were the same.
- (Advanced) VBox VMs and my host OS were still working even after enabling MSFT's Hyper-V

##### How I upgraded:

From Windows search box -> Settings -> Update & Security -> Activation -> "Go to the Store" link -> Upgrade to Windows 10/11 Pro -> Install -> "Yes, let's go".

The upgrade only took 5 mins on my 10 year old Lenovo Y40-80.

I think a restart was required were it said "installing windows updates _%" but I might be confusing that with the the restart I did after enabling Hyper-V. If the Hyper-V thing is confusing you, it's just a feature you can optionally enable after upgrading to Pro for running VM's of a Type 1 hypervisor.

Additionally, I did create a backup like the great people under this post had suggested. If you're like me, a backup sounds like a daunting task. I wanted to do what is called a "system image backup" which is a copy of EVERYTHING on your PC, but instead just copied my c:/Users/bwizz userfolder to a flash drive. If the upgrade had broke my PC, I would've lost my windows settings, & apps but least my most important stuff was safe.

Comment: You should have backups anyway.

Comment: Does the backup take up the same 147GB that Windows settings is telling me I've used on my C: drive

Comment: “Aside from the new features being added and minor changes here and there, will any files/apps/user-folders/environment-vars/Win10-Settings be deleted or modified in anyway?” - No

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Microsoft article
[Windows 10 upgrade paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/windows-10-upgrade-paths)
has this information :

[image]

The path from Windows 10 Home to Pro is marked with:

> Full upgrade is supported including personal data, settings, and applications

So nothing will be lost in the upgrade.

Nevertheless, I suggest to take careful backups before proceeding,
as problems are always possible. Ensure that the process is not
interrupted for any reason, and wait patiently if it takes some time
(which is normally about 10 minutes, but depends on many factors).

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I wish MSFT would've been a lil more exhaustively explicit, giving a lil more reassurance of what will and won't be deleted/modified though. I will do the backup, only prob, got 147GB on my PC and only 17GB left on my flash drive :'(

Comment: In Europe, a Windows Professional license is way more expensive than a 1 TB drive. Depending on your location, situation and income, I suggest you purchase additional storage for backup purposes.  Windows generally keeps your data safe [except when it does not](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2018/10/microsoft-fixes-october-update-file-deleting-bug-resumes-insider-testing/), so having a copy always is a good idea.

Comment: It is also possible to LEGALLY buy used licence for a franction of the price (~15EUR compared to ~190EUR, in CZ, personally did it yesterday) in EU :)

Comment: @Hermann I've never been good at keeping backups on Windows. I needed to research just to create a backup. There are "system image backups", Windows10 "File History" & old Windows7 backup utils, then you need external storage & it takes forev to copy everything. I ended up usin "TreeSize Free" for a better view of my filesystem. It helped me reduce the # of files on my drive from 780k to 466k & folders from 222k to 152k. Turns out the reason my user folder backup was takin forev WASN'T cause of its size but the total # of files & folders. Removing 196k files/folders sped it up a lot.

Comment: @mishan Surprisingly, Windows 10 Pro was free for me. It probably wasn't actually free though. I had Pro back in college, and it must have downgraded to home after I cleared my drive and reinstalled Windows 10 a few years ago. I guess this whole time I've had Pro but didn't realize :)

Comment: @Bwizz And now you've cleaned up your PC and have a system that, while not nice, can be set up much better :)

Answer (score 4):

Anything that is standard Windows will remain as is. Nothing will be deleted.

This upgrade is very similar to a Windows 10 Repair Install and I have done numerous repairs and never lost a thing.

So you will not experience any issue with this upgrade.

As with any change like this, do be sure you have a good backup before starting

Comment: Wanted to mark yours as answer as well but only one can be chosen :( Does the backup take up the same 147GB that Windows settings is telling me I've used on my C: drive, I've only got 17GB left on my flash drive

Comment: Or use a larger USB drive.  These are always handy

Comment: If I have 147GB used up on my SSD, will the backup also be 147GB?

Comment: That is a bit too tight. It might work - try and see.